# Inline conditional typeguard

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to accept either a string or an error for one of the arguments to my class, but then have a type guard such that when I use an inline conditional to check the type, it compiles.

It seems that typeguards for inline conditionals aren't supported, as evidenced from the three examples below, only the last of which compiles.

When I say "inline conditionals", I mean of the form `(<boolean statement>)? a : b` , not multiline if/else blocks, which for some reason are referred to as "inline" in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

UPDATE: this is more to do with javascript than typescript, which does support type guards for inline conditionals properly

```
export class MyError extends Error {
    public code; name; message

    constructor(code: number = -1, name: string = '', err?: Error | string) {
        super()
        this.name = name
        this.code = code 
        // no type guards
        this.message = this.name + (err)? ": " + (err instanceof Error)? err.message : err : ''
    }
}

export class MyError2 extends Error {
    public code; name; message

    constructor(code: number = -1, name: string = '', err?: Error | string) {
        super()
        this.name = name
        this.code = code 
        if(err) {
            // no type guards
            this.message = this.name + ": " + (err instanceof Error)? err.message : err
        } else {
            this.message = this.name
        }
    }
}

export class MyError3 extends Error {
    public code; name; message

    constructor(code: number = -1, name: string = '', err?: Error | string) {
        super()
        this.name = name
        this.code = code 
        // type guards... but at what cost to brevity
        this.message = this.name
        if(err) {
            if(err instanceof Error) {
                this.message += ": " + err.message
            } else {
                this.message += ": " + err
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you want your message as `<name>: <errorMessage>` and `err` will accept error object or error message, you can write the line as `this.message = \`${this.name}: ${err.message || err}\`;`. Also. should your type not be `err?: Error: string`? **String !== string**

Comment: I like it. The only thing is that if 'err' is undefined, we shouldn't have the ": ". So I should probably update the type to be `Error | string | null`, assuming strictNullChecks is enabled. Have updated string case, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does properly handle type guards used in ternary statements. Your use of parenthesis is leading to a different behavior than you expect in these statements though. If you format your code like this in your first two examples, everything should work correctly:

```
export class MyError extends Error {
    public code; name; message

    constructor(code: number = -1, name: string = '', err?: Error | String) {
        super()
        this.name = name
        this.code = code 
        this.message = this.name + (err ? ": " + (err instanceof Error ? err.message : err) : '')
    }
}

export class MyError2 extends Error {
    public code; name; message

    constructor(code: number = -1, name: string = '', err?: Error | String) {
        super()
        this.name = name
        this.code = code 
        if(err) {
            this.message = this.name + ": " + (err instanceof Error ? err.message : err)
        } else {
            this.message = this.name
        }
    }
}
```

I also believe that surrounding the whole ternary statement in parenthesis helps make it more readable, but that's a matter of personal opinion of course.

---

So what's wrong with your ternary statements? Because of [operator precedence rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), everything to the left of the first `?` is part of the same expression and thus all gets concatenated together, which changes the whole meaning of the ternary. Here's an example:

```
this.message = this.name + ": " + (err instanceof Error)? err.message : err
// same as: 
(this.name + ": " + (err instanceof Error)) ? err.message : err
// with values filled in:
"someName: true" ? err.message : err
```

And so, the code above will always evaluate `err.message` whether or not `err` is an `Error`

Comment: Yep, just checked with pure javascript and the problem is with the string concatenation. IE if we go `a = "a : " + (false)? "a" : (false)? "b" : "c"` we get `"a"`, but if we go `a = \`a : ${(false)? "a" : (false)? "b" : "c"}\``, we get "a : c" as expected. Doesn't appear to be a typescript problem at all.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because of [operator precedence rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), everything to the left of the first `?` is part of the same expression and thus all gets concatenated together, which changes the whole meaning of the ternary.

Comment: This works great: `this.message = \`${this.name}${(err)? " : " : (err instanceof Error)? err.message : err}\``, can you please update your answer with just this in the first example and I'll accept it - will be less confusing for people reading it later. ie demonstrating that bracketing not required to make it work.

Comment: Sure thing, either an interpolated string or additional parenthesis are both fine solutions

Comment: actually I've just realised I don't think it can be done the way I'd like in a template.

Comment: `this.message = this.name;
        if(err) {
            this.message += \` : ${(err instanceof Error)? err.message : err}\`
        }`